# AWK: how to extract in a block of text between two "\\" without considering the back to line

Tags: linux, awk

I would like to extract from a big block of text certain area
by setting the Field separator as "\\" however I'm always facing a problem as my text contain some single "\" and it seems to disturb the correct text extraction

INPUT:

```
1\1\GINC-R1430\FOpt\RB3LYP\6-31G(d,p)\C11H8\ROOT\22-Jan-2015\0\\#N b3l
 yp/6-31G** opt freq=noraman test Maxdisk=1Gb\\3\\0,1\C,-2.6997011275,0
 .2415237678,0.5867242856\C,-0.844160292,1.6395735777,-0.4268479833\C,-
 1.9760161741,1.2551936894,0.1361541401\C,-2.3923087914,-1.0358860734,-
 0.0557643955\C,0.3235980425,0.7875682734,-0.1356859882\C,-1.1093142432
 ,-1.3685423936,-0.3602591004\C,0.1496925203,-0.6332454104,-0.151244509
 2\H,-3.3806331312,0.2996137801,1.4332335206\H,-0.7633170455,2.45988827
 32,-1.1373018124\H,1.7187287121,2.4104501712,0.0387394407\H,-3.1756548
 236,-1.7742599934,-0.224548871\H,-0.9560852099,-2.3752668104,-0.747558
 6451\C,1.6076580336,1.3296735593,0.0442342156\C,2.5669578833,-0.875832
 9525,0.1864536297\H,3.4305876714,-1.5230597241,0.3068386649\C,1.309289
 0866,-1.4290100931,-0.0026907826\H,1.2013201753,-2.5103156986,-0.02627
 39389\C,2.7201916294,0.5158561201,0.2083031485\H,3.7045180838,0.956653
 9373,0.3361669809\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-A\HF=-423.9087698\
 RMSD=8.508e-09\RMSF=5.945e-05\Dipole=0.3132737,-0.297812,-0.0202519\Qu
 adrupole=2.0644665,1.7222772,-3.7867437,1.9108337,-0.4477432,-0.303338
 1\PG=C01 [X(C11H8)]\\@
```

OUTPUT I'm looking for:

```
0,1\C,-2.6997011275,0
 .2415237678,0.5867242856\C,-0.844160292,1.6395735777,-0.4268479833\C,-
 1.9760161741,1.2551936894,0.1361541401\C,-2.3923087914,-1.0358860734,-
 0.0557643955\C,0.3235980425,0.7875682734,-0.1356859882\C,-1.1093142432
 ,-1.3685423936,-0.3602591004\C,0.1496925203,-0.6332454104,-0.151244509
 2\H,-3.3806331312,0.2996137801,1.4332335206\H,-0.7633170455,2.45988827
 32,-1.1373018124\H,1.7187287121,2.4104501712,0.0387394407\H,-3.1756548
 236,-1.7742599934,-0.224548871\H,-0.9560852099,-2.3752668104,-0.747558
 6451\C,1.6076580336,1.3296735593,0.0442342156\C,2.5669578833,-0.875832
 9525,0.1864536297\H,3.4305876714,-1.5230597241,0.3068386649\C,1.309289
 0866,-1.4290100931,-0.0026907826\H,1.2013201753,-2.5103156986,-0.02627
 39389\C,2.7201916294,0.5158561201,0.2083031485\H,3.7045180838,0.956653
 9373,0.3361669809
```

The best I got so far was by using a simple:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\\\\" } ; {print $SELECTED AREA}'
```

where the selected area would be $4 if it is possible to set the field separator as "\\" without considering the "\"

Is someone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: I'm assuming that's all on one line and you broke it for sanity purposes but if so you should say that. If not `FS` isn't right. And I can't explain it (I've always had trouble with backslashes in awk) but eight backslashes seems to work.

Comment: Can you give us a definitive answer - IS your input split across 17 lines exactly as shown above or is it in fact all on one line and you've just split it up in your question to try to show the content without a scroll bar?

Comment: wrt #backslashes: /a\tc/ = /a tab c/ while /a\\tc/ = /a \ t c/. "a\\tc" = /a\tc/ = /a tab c/ so "a\\\\tc" = /a\\tc/ = /a \ t c/. So you can see that you need 4 backslashes in a string to create 1 backslash when that string is used in a regexp (or field separator) context.

Comment: @Ed Morton,  sorry for late reply due to time difference.
The file is just like that so yes the text block is not in one line
but made of multiple lines. So i don't know if the problem come from 
the back to line or the single backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all of eight backslashes to get what you want.

```
awk -F '\\\\\\\\' '{print $4}'
```

That's because you double them to get a literal backslash in a string, and double them again to get a literal backslash in a regex.

As an aside, that's an exceptionally poor choice of field delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer,
I agree about the poor field delimiter choice unfortunately my data
didn't gave me too much options to get what I want.

When I'm running  awk -F '\\\\\\\\' '{print $4}'
I got nothing 
and running awk -F '\\\\\\\\' '{print $3}'
give me this output:
0,1\C,-2.6997011275,0   that's all

So I think the single backslash is still messing with the delimitation.
Any idea how to get over these annoying single backslash?

Comment: @Jérémz If your data has been in one line, it would have worked like you want, but its on multiple lines.   Field Separator only works on records, and default records are one line,

Answer (score 0):

To get correct output, you need to set record separator to nothing like this:

```
awk -F'\\\\\\\\' '{print $4}' RS= file
0,1\C,-2.6997011275,0
 .2415237678,0.5867242856\C,-0.844160292,1.6395735777,-0.4268479833\C,-
 1.9760161741,1.2551936894,0.1361541401\C,-2.3923087914,-1.0358860734,-
 0.0557643955\C,0.3235980425,0.7875682734,-0.1356859882\C,-1.1093142432
 ,-1.3685423936,-0.3602591004\C,0.1496925203,-0.6332454104,-0.151244509
 2\H,-3.3806331312,0.2996137801,1.4332335206\H,-0.7633170455,2.45988827
 32,-1.1373018124\H,1.7187287121,2.4104501712,0.0387394407\H,-3.1756548
 236,-1.7742599934,-0.224548871\H,-0.9560852099,-2.3752668104,-0.747558
 6451\C,1.6076580336,1.3296735593,0.0442342156\C,2.5669578833,-0.875832
 9525,0.1864536297\H,3.4305876714,-1.5230597241,0.3068386649\C,1.309289
 0866,-1.4290100931,-0.0026907826\H,1.2013201753,-2.5103156986,-0.02627
 39389\C,2.7201916294,0.5158561201,0.2083031485\H,3.7045180838,0.956653
 9373,0.3361669809
```

Yo may need  `gnu awk` to set record selector to nothing.

Comment: You can set `RS=` with any awk, it's only when you want to set `RS` to more than 1 char that you need gawk.

Comment: `RS` is the `Record Separator` btw not record selector.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it thanks to ED Morton, Jotne and tripleee
By setting the RS i now have the correct output by using

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\\\\\\\\"; RS="\n\n";} {print $4}'
```

As I don't have any double blank lines it consider my block of text as one region now.
I never though about the RS  before as I'm mainly working on table parsing usually.
Thanks for that